# dockerfile-maven-plugin push image on gitlab-ci registry

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, docker-registry, dockerfile-maven-plugin

I'm using the dockerfile-maven-plugin from spotify:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
  <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.0</version>
  <configuration>
     <repository>${docker.registry}/${project.parent.artifactId}/${project.artifactId}</repository>
     <buildArgs>
       <JAR_FILE>target/${project.build.finalName}-exec.jar</JAR_FILE>
     </buildArgs>
   </configuration>
   <executions>
     <execution>
       <id>build</id>
       <phase>package</phase>
       <goals>
         <goal>build</goal>
       </goals>
     </execution>
     <execution>
        <id>push</id>
        <phase>install</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>push</goal>
        </goals>
     </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>
```

Locally, it works perfectly. The default config use a local registry :

```
<docker.registry>localhost:5000</docker.registry>
```

On gitlab-ci, to push the image I use the following

```
mvn install -Ddocker.registry=registry.gitlab.com/jeromevdl \
-Ddockerfile.username=gitlab-ci-token \
-Ddockerfile.password=$CI_BUILD_TOKEN
```

I'm not really sure about the registry, the username and password but I found that in the documentation and several samples.

I have the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.spotify:dockerfile-maven-plugin:1.4.0:push (push) on project connection-lookup: 
**Could not push image: denied: requested access to the resource is denied** -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.spotify:dockerfile-maven-plugin:1.4.0:push (push) on project connection-lookup: Could not push image
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:122)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main(MavenWrapperMain.java:50)

**Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Could not push image**
    at com.spotify.plugin.dockerfile.PushMojo.execute(PushMojo.java:90)
    at com.spotify.plugin.dockerfile.AbstractDockerMojo.tryExecute(AbstractDockerMojo.java:246)
    at com.spotify.plugin.dockerfile.AbstractDockerMojo.execute(AbstractDockerMojo.java:235)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    ... 27 more

**Caused by: com.spotify.docker.client.exceptions.DockerException: denied: requested access to the resource is denied**
    at com.spotify.plugin.dockerfile.LoggingProgressHandler.handleError(LoggingProgressHandler.java:105)
    at com.spotify.plugin.dockerfile.LoggingProgressHandler.progress(LoggingProgressHandler.java:63)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.ProgressStream.tail(ProgressStream.java:74)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.DefaultDockerClient.push(DefaultDockerClient.java:1309)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.DefaultDockerClient.push(DefaultDockerClient.java:1289)
    at com.spotify.plugin.dockerfile.PushMojo.execute(PushMojo.java:88)
    ... 31 more
```

Any idea on the configuration I should use on GitLab?

Comment: Looks like the URL to your registry is wrong. Have you testet it without variables? You can find the correct URL under 'Registry' under your project on your Gitlab instance.

Comment: You are right, there was missing something in the URL !